# Determine if a XIAO ESP32C3 is charging

Tags: battery, charging

When the XIAO ESP32C3 is charging a LiPo battery, there is a small LED on the board that lights up. Is there any way to access this information in an Arduino program?

Comment: yes, there is ... is that really all you want to know?

Comment: put an ldr or photodiode up to the LED. you can also use a clamp-style current meter to detect charge current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, according to the [schematic](https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/XIAO_WiFi/Resources/Seeeduino-XIAO-ESP32C3-SCH.pdf) it's not wired to any pin on MCU.

[image]